# JTextField can't be resized

Tags: java, swing, resize, jframe, jtextfield

I am new to JFrame, components and the such, but I'm trying to change a size of a specific text field so you can actually see what you put into it. Here's the code:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class InterestCalculator extends JFrame{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    JLabel desc = new JLabel("This is a simple interest calculator.\n"
            + " Enter three fields to get the fourth.");
    JLabel inteLabel = new JLabel("\nInterest: ");
    JTextField inte = new JTextField();

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        InterestCalculator comp = new InterestCalculator();
        comp.FrameHandler();
    }

        public void FrameHandler() {

        setSize(500, 500);
        setTitle("Template");
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        add(desc);
        add(inteLabel);
        add(inte);

        inte.setSize(new Dimension(100,15));

        validate();
    }
}
```

This is what comes out: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldwed.png
So, how can I fix this?

Comment: If you have multiple questions, ask them separately.

Comment: *"BONUS: to save some time for later,.."*  Ask a separate question NOW.  SO is a Q&A site, where each thread should have one specific question, not a help desk.

Comment: BTW - replace `setSize(500, 500);` with `pack()` after components are added.  The first is just a guess at how large the GUI needs to be.  The second will result in a size that is *exactly* as large as it needs to be.

Comment: Don't use validate. Instead the `setVisible(...)` statement should be the last statement executed AFTER you add all the components to the frame. Also, you should invoke `pack()` before the setVisible(...);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
JTextField inte = new JTextField();
```

Should set a number of columns, I.E.:

```
JTextField inte = new JTextField(10);
```

---

See also [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.)

The same applies to `setSize(..)`.

Comment: plus one, but the major issue should come from setLayout(new FlowLayout());